# How to create directories with names that are differing in case? (a case-sensitive CreateDirectory function)

Tags: windows, winapi, case-sensitive, file-handling

Is there a way to do this? I use CreateFile with the FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS flag to create files with case-sensitive names. Now I need something like that for directories too.

Example: 
CreateDirectory("aaa", NULL); 
and 
CreateDirectory("AAA", NULL); 
would result it 2 different directories. :)

Comment: I am amazed that Windows lets you do this for files. I will be even more amazed if a method is found that works on directories.

Comment: @Mark It's only on file systems that support case-insensitive file names. Think server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native API like David suggested (case-sensitivity is determined by the parameters to `InitializeObjectAttributes()`)

Alternatively, you can use [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) and specify FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY for dwFlagsAndAttributes and CREATE_NEW for dwCreationDisposition.

Comment: The documentation for CreateFile says "An application cannot create a directory by using CreateFile, therefore only the OPEN_EXISTING value is valid for dwCreationDisposition for this use case. To create a directory, the application must call CreateDirectory or CreateDirectoryEx." Is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to resort to the native API and call [`NtCreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28VS.85%29.aspx). I'm afraid I can't help you call the rather frightening API, but I don't believe there is anything else that could possibly allow this.